# One string containing a substring in bash - not working

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I have this code:

```
#!/bin/bash

temp=("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee")
sub="cc"

for i in $temp
    do if [[ $i == *"$sub"* ]]; then
    echo "contains sub"
    fi
done
```

Why isn't the substring is ever contained in the temp during the loop? (the if statement is never true, and the echo is never reached).

I would imagine that this code goes through the temp one by one (e.g. "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" and so on) and compares each of these to the sub "cc", to see if the sub is contained in any of the strings in temp, but clearly there is something I'm not getting.

Comment: `temp=("aaa" "bbb" "ccc" "ddd" "eee")` (note the absence of `','`)

Comment: ... and use `for i in "${temp[@]}"` to access its elements.

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues.

1. remove the `','` from the array initialization,
2. change your loop to `for i in "${temp[@]}"`,
3. since this is bash, better to use `do if [[ $i =~ "$sub" ]]; then`

(note: `$sub` unquoted will be treated as a regular expression)

Putting it altogether:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

temp=("aaa" "bbb" "ccc" "ddd" "eee")
sub="cc"

for i in "${temp[@]}"
    do if [[ $i =~ "$sub" ]]; then
    echo "$i - contains sub"
    fi
done
```

**Example Output**

```
$ bash s.sh
ccc - contains sub
```

Comment: Note that `[[ $i =~ $sub ]]` will treat the value of `$sub` as a regular expression pattern; this only matters if it contains any regular expression metacharacters, but if it does, this can cause unexpected results. If you want it treated as a plain string, double-quote it (i.e. use either `[[ $i == *"$sub"* ]]` or `[[ $i =~ "$sub" ]]`) to avoid interpretation of metacharacters.

Comment: Why is `=~ "$sub"` better than `== *"$sub"*`?

Comment: @JohnKugelman No technical reason, both will match, but `=~` provides the flexibility of using a REGEX instead of a simple glob match. Nothing wrong with `[[ $i == *"$sub"* ]]`, selection of `=~` was more out of habit with `[[ ... ]]` than anything else.

Comment: `=~` looks better and it's shorter

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help :-)

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck with your scripting.